# Gnome-Terminal - How do I reset keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, gnome-terminal, shortcuts, dconf

I have an issue with the Gnome-terminal since early on where I was unable to copy from the terminal( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ), even with text being highlighted, so I made the mistake of disabling it to see if re-enabling it and inputting the shortcut back would fix it.

However, when I press those keys, the tab with "New accelerator..." won't pick up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. It will only do either <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I have tried several steps from answers I've found online in terms to reset the `gnome-terminal` to default settings, such as removing the `.conf` files, using the `dconf-editor` to remove profile info, removing and purging the application, etc. None of these seemed to have worked. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Hi DGs, just curious, but did you manage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Short answer

This setting is stored in the `dconf` database. 
The command to *restore* the default keyboard shortcut to paste in the terminal is:

```
dconf reset /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/paste
```

or to set it to a specific value:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/paste "'<Primary><Shift>v'"
```

Unfortunately, there is no `gsettings` key for it, so you need to write to `dconf` directly.

---

#### The question is however

...why it didn't stick when setting the key from the GUI. In case of errors, you will find out in the output of the command(s) above.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thank you for your help. 

When I run this command it works and it successfully resets the key bindings. However, when I try to actually highlight something and press these keys, they do not copy. The paste function seems to work, however. Does the <Primary> mean left shift or right shift? 
It seems as if though it only picks up on the right shift key. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @DGs could you run `dconf dump / | grep Primary` and seee what combinations with `Primary` are set? `Primary` is the Ctrl key.

Comment: An additional question is... why can't you do this from the Preferences menu?